# Is jQuery html("htmlString") performed synchronously OR asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My question may be obvious to some, but just want to confirm before implementing further. Is content replaced by the method jQuery.html("htmlString") guaranteed to be completely loaded before the next line of Javascript is executed?

More specifically, what I want to know is whether or not

```
<div id="SomeContent"></div>
```

will exist just before code "line 123" (as shown in code block 3 below) is executed. Example below:

parent page:

```
...
$.post('/Controller/GetPartialPage', { data: 'abc' }, function (partialPage)
{
    $('#PageContent').hide().html(partialPage).fadeIn(250);
    $(document).trigger("PartialPageLoaded");
});
...
```

partial page:

```
...
<script src="~/Scripts/example.js"></script>
...
<div id="SomeContent"></div>
...
```

example.js:

```
...
$(document).bind("PartialPageLoaded", function ()
{
    $.post('/Controller/GetOtherContent', { data: 'xyz' }, function (result)
    {
        $('#SomeContent').hide().html(result).fadeIn(100); // line 123
    });
});
...
```

Comment: The `html` function is completely synchronous, However your example depends on the code in the `GetPartialPage()` function - which I assume is an async AJAX request which is leading to problems. Could you add the code from that function to your question.

Comment: I have updated my code to show the method which gets the partial page content.

Comment: The DOM is completely parsed from the HTML and can be accessed, however the *contents* (like external scripts or images) will be fetched asynchronously.